# MATLAB reshape matrix converting indices to row index

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

Is it possible to reshape matrices such that

```
x1 = 
    1   5
    3   4
    4   3
    7   1
```

becomes

```
x2 =
    5
    NaN
    4
    3
    NaN
    NaN
    1
```

or vice versa, where the first column in `x1` is an index that corresponds to a row# in `x2`?

Answer (score 5):

Create an array with NaNs and fill it with values:

```
x2          = NaN(max(x1(:,1)),1);
x2(x1(:,1)) = x1(:,2);
```

Now, if zero padding is acceptable, then you can simply use the second line directly without first creating `out`.

**Alternatively**, for your specific example (no overlapping indices) the same result is achieved with:

```
accumarray(x1(:,1),x1(:,2),[],[],NaN)
```

**Going the other way**

```
idx = ~isnan(x2);
x1  = [find(idx) x2(idx)];
```

Comment: How would I go the other way? I.e. from `x2` to `x1`

Comment: for going the other way, I keep getting `??? Error using ==> isnan
Not enough input arguments.`

Comment: Sorry! That's perfect! There's probably a way to get around this by playing around with the output of my other calculations, but this will do brilliantly.